# Outlook 2010 : "An error occurred when setting schedule permissions"

Tags: microsoft-outlook

**Computer**: Windows 7 x64 Enterprise.  Office 2010 with Outlook 2010.  Exchange account and a couple of IMAP accounts connected to the Outlook profile.

**Error**:  When attempting to share the calendar with anyone (selected from the address book) by click on "Calendar Permissions" seen here

[image]

You can add or remove people without issue, except that no matter what, even if nothing is done, just opening the sharing window and closing it, you get an error message that says

*"An error occurred when setting schedule permissions"*

Verified that the issue doesnt actually effect the sharing, or the general setting of permissions.  The error however is disconcerting to my user, and I would like to alleviate the problem if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to select the user from the GAL instead of manually typing their address.  For instance, the email address "User@ContosoLong.com" works, but the shortened version of that which my company also owns, and forwards all mail to will not.

Works: user@contosolong.com

Doesnt work: user@CTL.com (forwards to contosolong.com) does not